# How to fetch original request headers using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

What is the 'Angular' way to retrieve incoming request headers? I'm not asking how to set headers in the request or response of an Angular Application.

For example in the following request, How to retrieve the `token` header within my Angular controller:

```
curl 'http://localhost:3000/index.html' -H 'token: mytoken'
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that this isn't an angular function.  How would you do it using ordinary Javascript?

Comment: That's obviously not an angular function. My question is towards, How would you retrieve a particular header from within an Angular 'function'. Imagine this curl is pointing to my angular application, how do you get the 'token' header?

Comment: The same way you would do it using ordinary Javascript.

Comment: Is that the Angular way?

Comment: There is no Angular way.  The purpose of Angular is to provide MVVM facilities to a browser for frontend data binding yada yada.  It has nothing to say about browser headers, except insofar as it may or may not use some for its own purposes.

Comment: Willing to try, what would that be?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript

Comment: I saw that. That captures a response header. Not a request. Please read the question carefully. Incoming request. Say I have an angular app running, I run that curl pointing to it. How do you get the token header?

Comment: Are you referring to an authorization token header?

Comment: yeah. that for example, or a language header